# Winrar Sfx get Icon from executable

Tags: exe, executable, winrar, self-extracting, software-packaging

i don't know if it is right to ask here but I have a really quick question.

I have an executable file which already has an icon and I plan to use winrar sfx to create a mini installer for it.
My question is: is there a way for Winrar sfx to copy the icon of my exe?
like what you do with autorun.inf, where you simple code "ICON=setup.exe" or something like that.

I know I can manually specify it on creation, but the project is still on going and it would really really save me more time.

Also I have accidentally deleted the icon for my executable. (that's the reason why I'm asking this to save me time researching how to re extract the icon.)

thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use a *.exe or *.dll file containing icon resources as source for the SFX icon. The source file must be a real *.ico file with at least 1 icon. The icon file can include also several icons in various sizes like 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48, ... The functions of Windows load and display automatically the most suitable size of the icon.

There are lots of free applications which can extract icons from *.exe or *.dll files like multimedia viewer [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) or [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).